# this.text Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a inline function that works fine.  When the link is clicked it puts the text into the textField:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('textField').value =(this.text);">someText</a>
```

What i want to do is be able to call the above as a function instead of writing it inline.  Example:

```
function setValue() {
      document.getElementById('dd').value =(this.text);
}
```

and be able to call it like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="setValue();">someText</a>
```

I thought it would be simple but for some reason it is not work and giving me error in firebug. I think it has something to do with "this.text" being called from a function instead of inline.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, what does the error say? You seem to not know this but errors actually provide useful information about themselves (a message and the line number).

Answer (score 2):

Why not take it one step further and put the event binding code outside of the markup too? [Separating your behavior from presentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is a good idea.

```
$("#anchor_selector").click(function () {
    $("#dd").val(this.text);
});
```

I would apply an `id` attribute to your anchor and use it in the selector. Or you can use one of the [many other selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)s out there to target your link.

Answer (score 1):

```javascript
function setValue( text ) {
   jQuery('#dd').val( text );
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="setValue( jQuery( this ).text() );">someText</a>
```

Comment: In the OP's example, `text` isn't being invoked (if indeed it's a function).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the context, otherwise `this` will be the global scope (window):

```
<a href="#" onclick="setValue(this);">someText</a>

function setValue(context) {
      document.getElementById('dd').value = $(context).text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` is being lost. Try setting `setValue()` to take a reference to the element as the first param, and then pass `this` in the handler.